# Parametric Polymorphism in java

Tags: java

What is parametric polymorphism in java

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-02-2000/jw-02-jsr.html

Answer (score 2):

For a good introductory description of parametric polymorphism, refer to this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism#Parametric_polymorphism).

In Java, generics are a form of parametric polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, overloading is also reffered as parametric polymorphism as far as you would have  methods with the same name but with different parameters. Usually those methods have the same purpose so you have different (polymorph) ways of calling the same name.

Comment: overloading is usually considered "ad hoc polymorphism"